# Cells calculated by marco functions are not recalculated after iteration

Tags: excel, vba, function

I see several comments related to my problem but having tried these various solutions without resolving the issue I will ask this.

I have a complicated Excel workbook saved in Excel 2010 `.xlsm` format. It has multiple sheets and is set up for manual iteration to arrive at the final solution. **My problem is that many cells that reference macro functions do not recalculate properly**. I have tried a number of things such as the following and the sheet that is selected will recalculate properly while annother sheet in the workbook that was completly calculate will then have cells where there were proper numbers are now blank.

These are some of the statements I have tried.

```
 ActiveWorkbook.ForceFullCalculation = True
 Application.CalculateFullRebuild
 Application.Calculate
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The issue may be in your VBA functions: if you do not reference ranges explicitly in a UDF then it may only calculate correctly when it's on the ActiveSheet.  Unless you can show some of your code it's impossible to suggest anything further.

Comment: I agree with Tim, there might be an issue with your VBA functions. I am suspecting that functions may be running on the wrong sheet. So my suggestion is that when you are running macros that are referencing different sheets, I suggest explicitly writing out which sheets you want your macros to be running on (ie. Worksheets("mysheetname")).....

Comment: If you want your UDF's to reference specific sheets, then either use `Application.Caller.Worksheet` (the worksheets hosting the formula) or - if your UDF has range parameters - use thse ranges to access the parent sheet.